# OCR Library (Python)

Tags: linux, ocr

I am searching a library or tool to do OCR.

Below is an example of a scan.

Needed features:

- OCR for full page. Should detect several areas and different font sizes
- Running on Linux (SuSE 42.3 and Ubuntu 16.04)
- No online service. The OCR should happen without internet connection
- Needs to be integrated into Python. Via subprocess would be ok, as library is prevered
- Commercial software is ok.
- Optional: Detect hand written words

[image]

Sad, even the bounty a gave did not help. There was only a solution based on open source software. I think there are commercial ocr engines available which have much better results - but this is only a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)) via the [`pyocr`](https://github.com/openpaperwork/pyocr) library.

You will need these packages:

- [tesseract-ocr](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/tesseract-ocr)
- [tesseract-ocr-deu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/tesseract-ocr-deu)
- [python3-pyocr](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3-pyocr)

Here is a sample script based on the `pyocr` documentation:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

# https://github.com/openpaperwork/pyocr

from PIL import Image
import sys

import pyocr
import pyocr.builders

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.stderr.write("Usage: {} /path/to/image.png".format(sys.argv[0]))
image_path = sys.argv[1]

tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
tool_to_use = None
for tool in tools:
    if tool.get_name() == 'Tesseract':
        tool_to_use = tool

if tool_to_use is None:
    sys.stderr.write("Missing dependency:")
    sys.stderr.write("apt install 'tesseract-ocr'")
    sys.exit(1)

lang = 'deu'
langs = tool_to_use.get_available_languages()
if lang not in langs:
    sys.stderr.write("Missing dependency:")
    sys.stderr.write("apt install 'tesseract-ocr-deu'")
    sys.exit(1)

txt = tool_to_use.image_to_string(
    Image.open(image_path),
    lang=lang,
    builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
)
sys.stdout.write(txt)
```

It takes about 9 seconds to process your example image on my laptop.

```
$ /usr/bin/time --output=time.log --verbose python3 do_ocr.py fAtTn.png > out.txt
$ grep 'wall clock' time.log 
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:09.11
```

The overhead from the Python library is probably minimal,
since the time is comparable to running the `tesseract` command directly.

```
$ /usr/bin/time --output=time-tesseract.log --verbose tesseract -l 'deu' fAtTn.png fAtTn
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.01 with Leptonica
$ grep 'wall clock' time-tesseract.log 
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:09.54
```

(I am running Debian 9, not Ubuntu 16.04, but they should be comparable.)

Here is the output with extraneous newlines suppressed:

```
05.10.2017 IS—U: Laufkarte (ISU) Einbau HKWLSS Original Seite 1

Auftrag zum Geräteeinbau Sparte?®

Auftrag 4043400 ServicemeldungE%C%j()é?%?ä3
Techn.?latz 1030423
Straße: Nr. 63 261/10

Einbauzähler
Serialnummer ‚ SW;K;ÄÄC .................
Materialtyp ..................................
Herstellemummer' ..................................

Zählerstand HT

Zählerstand NT 6}

Bestätigung des Zählerstandes vom Geschäftspartner:

Gebrauchsfähigkeitsprüfung Hauptprüfung nach TRGI Pkt.?
Leckmenge l/h dicht O

_ €?ßäää?ä ???» .............

Anlage .....

Zugeordnete Verbrauchssrelle
Übernahme Beschriftung am Zählerplatz

Geräleplatznummer

Beschreibung Geräleplaiz

Brancizenxchlüssel ‘

weitere Wichtige Infbrmationen zur Anlage ..........................................
Datum ....... &“!äQ‘fia ........................
. 953 ,
Unterschnﬂ Monteur ........... ".”. . . f .........................
ÄQB€
Bearbeitungsvermerk technisch gg; ] kauﬂnännisch
Datmn/Signum/Slempel
```

Tesseract will struggle with the handwritten sections,
but the typeset text is mostly intact.

Comment: 9 seconds is quite long these days. I am willing to buy a library to get better results.

Comment: Have you tried it on your machine? Tesseract has pretty good accuracy, but it is CPU intensive.